# Unable to import native (Swift) iOS view into React Native project - requireNativeComponent was not found in the UIManager

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, react-native-native-module

**Preface**: this error message with `requireNativeComponent` appears often on StackOverflow, mostly resolved with the [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61832232/invariant-violation-requirenativecomponent-rncwebview-was-not-found-in-the-u) such as disintegrating the pods, and then performing a new `pod install` and recompiling.

Unfortunately this has not worked out in my case.

--

I am trying to lift a simple view, written in Swift, into my React Native `0.71.x` project.

iOS Swift code `TestViewManager.swift`

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@objc (TestViewManager)
class TestViewManager: RCTViewManager {
  override func view() -> UIView! {

    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Hello from parent"
    label.sizeToFit()
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = .link
    
    return label
  }
  
  override static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
    return true
  }
  
}
```

The Objective-C implementation file `TestViewManager.m`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import "React/RCTViewManager.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(TestViewManager, RCTViewManager);

@end
```

In React Native, the `TestView.js` file

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {requireNativeComponent} from 'react-native';

const RNTestView = requireNativeComponent('TestViewManager');

export default class TestView extends Component {
    render() {
        return <RNTestView />;
    }
}
```

Everything appears to be extremely vanilla, similar to this person's set up (with same issue, [unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74687707/requirenativecomponent-was-not-found-in-the-uimanager-react-native-ios))

However, the outcome is the message: `Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "TestViewManager" was not found in the UIManager.`

What am I doing incorrectly?

[image]

Comment: is an advice to never use React Native going to get me banned? I think that's the best option really.

Comment: I am in your boat @rapiddevice, but unfortunately this task requires the use of react native. In fact, it is based on a react native project, and I am tasked with writing a poorly optimized component in native Swift. 

Any tips would be much appreciated.